# Xcode: Get rid of forward class warning

Tags: objective-c, xcode, warnings

In Xcode, I have a forward class declared so as to avoid a circular import e.g.

```
@class MyClass;
```

And then I do a method call on that class e.g.

```
[MyClass myMethod];
```

But I get a forward class warning e.g.

> warning: receiver 'MyClass' is a
>   forward class and corresponding
>   @interface may not exist

How can I hide those across my whole project?

Comment: Also, I don't want to hide any other type of warning.

Comment: Dupe: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/322597/objective-c-class-vs-import

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You use forward class declarations in your *header* file to prevent circular imports.

You must still import the MyClass header in your .m file.  The circular import problem doesn't exist with .m files.

Answer (score 3):

My [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/834955/how-can-i-solve-this-problem-with-bidirectional-dependencies-in-objective-c-class/835004#835004) to a similar question may be of use here.

The basic concept is this:

use `@class` in header files, and then use `#import` in the .m files.